# Merge data frames based on substrings- python

Tags: python, pandas, substring

I have two data frames where I want to merge based on a column in one df having substring in second df, how can I do it ?

Here is 1st dataframe

```
Flower     Id     city 
Jasmine 1023 hawai
Lotus   3405 st Jose
BudRose 4409 Miami
Lily    2457 Washington
```

2nd dataframe

```
Flower   Id         city 
Jasmine 1023LD Hawai
Lily    2457MH Washington
Lily    3346HK Washington
```

I need to merge these by `Flower`, `city` and first 4 characters of the `Id`
Thereby
The 2nd lily shouldn’t come in the result.

The merged dataset should look like this

```
Flower   Id         city 
Jasmine 1023LD Hawai
Lily    2457MH Washington
```

How do I do the merge using substring ?

Thank you !!

Comment: actually second Lotus should look same way as first Lotus. 
Yes let me try to see how I can split into columns,

Comment: Done, how do I put the dataframe inside tag or something so it will appear like columns and not string

Comment: done please see

Comment: not really. The second Lilys Id doesnt have a matched Id in the first dataframe..

Comment: for merging, the flower is same between 2 dataframes, city is same and first 4 characters of Id should be the same... hope that makes sense..

Comment: sorry -i need to be better at creating posts..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For substr merging on the first 4 characters of `Id` and the `Flower` column, try something like:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Flower': ["Jasmine", "Lotus", "BudRose", "Lily"],
                    'Id': ["1023", "3405", "4409", "2457"],
                    'City': ["Hawai", "St Jose", "Miami", "Washington"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Flower': ["Jasmine", "Lily", "Lily"],
                    'Id': ["1023LD", "2457MH", "3346HK", ],
                    'City': ["Hawai", "Washington", "Washington"]})


def get_substr(x):
    return x['Id'].str[:4]


merged_df = df1.assign(merge_with_x=get_substr) \
    .merge(df2.assign(merge_with_x=get_substr),
           on=['Flower', 'City', 'merge_with_x'],
           suffixes=['_x', '/z']) \
    .filter(regex=r'Flower|City|.*/z')

# Fix Column Names
merged_df.columns = merged_df.columns.str.rstrip('/z')

# Fix Column Order
merged_df = merged_df[['Flower', 'Id', 'City']]

print(merged_df)
```

Output:

```
    Flower      Id        City
0  Jasmine  1023LD       Hawai
1     Lily  2457MH  Washington
```

---

#### How It Works

Add Column to both `DF` with the desired substr:

```py
def get_substr(x):
    return x['Id'].str[:4]

print(df1.assign(merge_with_x=get_substr))
print(df2.assign(merge_with_x=get_substr))
```

```
    Flower    Id        City merge_with_x
0  Jasmine  1023       Hawai         1023
1    Lotus  3405     St Jose         3405
2  BudRose  4409       Miami         4409
3     Lily  2457  Washington         2457
    Flower      Id        City merge_with_x
0  Jasmine  1023LD       Hawai         1023
1     Lily  2457MH  Washington         2457
2     Lily  3346HK  Washington         3346
```

---

Merge on Flower and substr:

```py
print(df1.assign(merge_with_x=get_substr)
      .merge(df2.assign(merge_with_x=get_substr),
             on=['Flower', 'City', 'merge_with_x'],
             suffixes=['_x', '/z']))
```

```
    Flower  Id_x        City merge_with_x    Id/z
0  Jasmine  1023       Hawai         1023  1023LD
1     Lily  2457  Washington         2457  2457MH
```

---

Then filter out columns created by merge:

```py
print(df1.assign(merge_with_x=get_substr)
      .merge(df2.assign(merge_with_x=get_substr),
             on=['Flower', 'City', 'merge_with_x'],
             suffixes=['_x', '/z'])
      .filter(regex=r'Flower|City|.*/z'))
```

```
    Flower        City    Id/z
0  Jasmine       Hawai  1023LD
1     Lily  Washington  2457MH
```

---

Lastly Cleanup Column Names and Order:

```
merged_df.columns = merged_df.columns.str.rstrip('/z')
merged_df = merged_df[['Flower', 'Id', 'City']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.merge(df2.groupby('Flower').first(), how='inner', on='Flower').rename(columns={'Id_y':'Id',
                        'city_y':'city'}).drop(['Id_x', 'city_x'], 1)
```

**Output**

```
    Flower  Id      city
0   Jasmine 1023LD  Hawai
1   Lily    2457MH  Washington
```